# How will I use BackendListenerClient like GraphiteBackendListenerClient and InfluxdbBackendListenerClient from Jmeter API using java code?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, influxdb

I want to use `GraphiteBackendListner` and `InfluxdbBackendListnerClient` using JMeter API in my java code.

My purpose is to replicate the GraphiteBackendListner and InfluxdbBackendListnerClient and push the test metrics to grafana for monitoring, likewise we do in GUI mode, but using Jmeter API **java code**.

The below script consists of the following samplers:

> Load Url(Invoke the sample e-commerce URL)
>
> Login(Used AuthManager to use Login Credentials)
>
> Search(Search a value/keyword/argument on the search box of the sample website)
>
> Viewcart(The view the items of the cart)
>
> Checkout(Payment Gateway Page)
>
> Confirmation(Order Placed is successful Page)

I would like to have a sample code on how its, done.

**Here is my code snippet**

```
 package com.blazemeter.demo;

 import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
 import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
 import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
 import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
 import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
 import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Authorization;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.gui.AuthPanel;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.gui.HeaderPanel;
 import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
 import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
 import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
 import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
 import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
 import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
 import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
 import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
 import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
 import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class JMeterFromAPI {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String jmeterHome = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-4.0";
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();
    
    // Create HTTP Header Manager
    HeaderManager head = new HeaderManager();
    head.add(new Header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"));
    head.add(new Header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"));
    head.add(new Header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"));
    head.add(new Header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"));
    head.add(new Header("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"));
    head.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("header_manager_title")); // $NON-NLS-1$
    head.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
    head.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());
    
    // HTTP Sampler - Load URL
    HTTPSamplerProxy LoadUrl = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    LoadUrl.setDomain("sampledomain");
    LoadUrl.setPort(80);
    LoadUrl.setPath("/");
    LoadUrl.setMethod("GET");
    LoadUrl.setName("Load Url");
    LoadUrl.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    LoadUrl.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // HTTP Sampler - Login
    HTTPSamplerProxy Login = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    Login.setDomain("sampledomain");
    Login.setPort(80);
    Login.setPath("/account/login");
    Login.setMethod("GET");
    Login.setName("Login");
    Login.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    Login.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // Create HTTP Authorization Manager
    AuthManager manager = new AuthManager();
    Authorization authorization = new Authorization();
    authorization.setURL("sampleURL");
    authorization.setUser("sampleusername");
    authorization.setPass("samplepassword");
    manager.addAuth(authorization);
    manager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("auth_manager_title")); // $NON-NLS-1$
    manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, AuthManager.class.getName());
    manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, AuthPanel.class.getName());
       
    // HTTP Sampler - Search
    HTTPSamplerProxy Search = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    Search.setDomain("sampledomain");
    Search.setPort(80);
    Search.setPath("/search");
    Search.setMethod("GET");
    Search.setName("Search");
    Search.addArgument("Item", "Mobiles");
    Search.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    Search.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // HTTP Sampler - Viewcart
    HTTPSamplerProxy Viewcart = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    Viewcart.setDomain("sampledomain");
    Viewcart.setPort(80);
    Viewcart.setPath("/viewcart");
    Viewcart.setMethod("GET");
    Viewcart.setName("Viewcarts");
    Viewcart.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    Viewcart.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // HTTP Sampler - Checkout
    HTTPSamplerProxy Checkout = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    Checkout.setDomain("sampledomain");
    Checkout.setPort(80);
    Checkout.setPath("/checkout/init");
    Checkout.setMethod("GET");
    Checkout.setName("Checkout");
    Checkout.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    Checkout.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // HTTP Sampler - Confirmation
    HTTPSamplerProxy Confirmation = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    Confirmation.setDomain("sampledomain");
    Confirmation.setPort(80);
    Confirmation.setPath("/confirmation");
    Confirmation.setMethod("GET");
    Confirmation.setName("Confirmation");
    Confirmation.setComment("Your Order is Confirmed");
    Confirmation.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    Confirmation.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    
    // Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();
    
    // Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(3);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setDuration(3);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    // Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Ecommerce Website");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());
            
    // HTTP Request Sampler and Header Manager
    HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
    httpRequestTree.add(LoadUrl,head);
    httpRequestTree.add(Login, head);
    httpRequestTree.add(Login, manager);
    httpRequestTree.add(Search,head);
    httpRequestTree.add(Viewcart,head);
    httpRequestTree.add(Checkout,head);
    httpRequestTree.add(Confirmation,head);
    
    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);
    
    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jmx"));

    //Add Summarizer output
    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }
    
    // Store Execution Results into a .csv file
    String csvFile = jmeterHome + "/bin/result.csv";
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename(csvFile);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

    // Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
   
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really "your" code snippet my expectation is that you should be able to figure out how to add a listener yourself. The class you're looking for is [BackendListener](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/BackendListener.html)

However just in case for anyone else's reference:

```
BackendListener backendListener = new BackendListener();
backendListener.setName("Backend Listner");
Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
arguments.addArgument("graphiteMetricsSender", "org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.TextGraphiteMetricsSender", "=");
arguments.addArgument("graphiteHost", "localhost", "=");
arguments.addArgument("graphitePort", "2003", "=");
arguments.addArgument("rootMetricsPrefix", ".jmeter", "=");
arguments.addArgument("samplersList", "bar", "=");
arguments.addArgument("useRegexpForSamplersList", "false", "=");
arguments.addArgument("percentiles", "50;90;95", "=");
backendListener.setArguments(arguments);
backendListener.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, backendListener.getClassname());
backendListener.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, BackendListenerGui.class.getName());

// Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(backendListener);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);
```

Check out the following material to learn more about what above metrics mean and how to setup backend database and Grafana dashboard:

- [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)